# Move item from one select list to another

Tags: jquery, html

### Problem while filtering list box and move item to another select list

I got a strange scenario while I am moving one list box item to another list box using jQuery.

I made a filter on source list box when I type text in input box then first list box give me filtered result as I required. Then I click on Add button <kbd>></kbd> item moved to right side, it is also OK, 
but when I click on input text box and press back slash, right shifted item goes back to lift list. which is wrong.

Can anyone help on this?

[See Working here](http://demo4.digiwebtech.com/testpage.html)

```
 <script>
    var showOnlyOptionsSimilarToText = function (selectionEl, str, isCaseSensitive) {
        if (isCaseSensitive)
            str = str.toLowerCase();
        // cache the jQuery object of the <select> element
        var $el = $(selectionEl);
        if (!$el.data("options")) {
            // cache all the options inside the <select> element for easy recover
            $el.data("options", $el.find("option").clone());
        }
        var newOptions = $el.data("options").filter(function () {
            var text = $(this).text();
            if (isCaseSensitive)
                text = text.toLowerCase();
            return text.match(str);
        });
        $el.empty().append(newOptions);
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAddAllBeneficiaries,#btnRemoveAllBeneficiaries").click(function (event) {
            var ID = $(event.target).attr("ID");
            if (ID == "btnRemoveAllBeneficiaries") { if (!confirm("Do you want to remove item")) { return; } }
            var ChooseFrom = ID == "btnAddAllBeneficiaries" ? "#BeneficiariesList" : "#assignedBeneficiariesList";
            var moveTo = ID == "btnAddAllBeneficiaries" ? "#assignedBeneficiariesList" : "#BeneficiariesList";

            var SelectData = $(ChooseFrom + " > option").toArray();
            $(moveTo).append(SelectData);
            SelectData.remove;
        });


        $("#btnAddBeneficiaries,#btnRemoveBeneficiaries").click(function (event) {
            var ID = $(event.target).attr("ID");
            if (ID == "btnRemoveBeneficiaries") { if (!confirm("Do you want to remove item")) { return; } }
            var ChooseFrom = ID == "btnAddBeneficiaries" ? "#BeneficiariesList" : "#assignedBeneficiariesList";
            var moveTo = ID == "btnAddBeneficiaries" ? "#assignedBeneficiariesList" : "#BeneficiariesList";

            var SelectData = $(ChooseFrom + " :selected").toArray();
            $(moveTo).append(SelectData);
            SelectData.remove;
        });

        $("#SearchBeneficiaries").on("keyup", function () {
            var userInput = $("#SearchBeneficiaries").val();
            showOnlyOptionsSimilarToText($("#BeneficiariesList"), userInput, true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem: If you cache your options the first time in state A, then you move them (State B) and then you enter the method again, your "cached" options are not up-to-date and from state A! So filtering the options does not work with the manipulated set of options in state B but with the original ones from state A when you first entered the function.

They are old and contain the ones that you just moved. Appending them again you grab them whereever they are (especially when they are in the new list now) and put them in the old one again.

Solution: If any item is added/removed your cached items have to be manipulated (Options added/removed). Then your bug will be fixed.

Look at this code. You need to complete and add it into both of your clickhandlers:

```
            //Keep "cache" up-to-date
            var cacheList = $("#BeneficiariesList").data('options');
            if(cacheList) {
                //List exists, manipulate it
                if(ID == "btnAddAllBeneficiaries") {
                    //Remove SelectData-items from the cacheList
                }
                else {
                    //Add SelectData-items to the cacheList
                }
            }
```

Comment: Look at my edit, the snipplet should help you. The implementation itself is still your work.